# Is there a way to put a background inside SVG

Tags: svg

I need to make an SVG that is to be used as a background-image with "cover", so the tile in the mosaic could be rescaled. 
I'd like to have the icon at a fixed size and the posibility to always fill with a background color, because, to make matters more complicated, my image is going to be inside a container that is inside the tile
[this is my example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbjqy.png)
my icon should go inside that red outlined box, fixed size and the background in gray
could i get that done?

Comment: Just use multiple backgrounds - background color first, and then your icon on top of that ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Backgrounds_and_Borders/Using_multiple_backgrounds

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include a [mcve] with your question. It is not especially clear what you want to achieve.